# Can I install Ubuntu on my samsung galaxy tab 2 GT-P5113?

Tags: samsung, ubuntu-touch

Hi is there a way to install ubuntu on my Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.1" Model# GT-P5113 I wanted to use the nexus 7 intaller but it requires "fastboot" but my tab does not have fastboot as it has a TI OMAP Processor not a Tegra. so is there a manual method to get the same result as the nexus 7? My device does support ODIN flashing And clockwork mod..

Comment: Have you tried at XDA-developers?.

Comment: Yes i have and the only answers i got was the rootstock/chroot method or that they did not know most didnt know too much about the nexus 7 installer

Comment: Well using the Nexus 7 installer will probably brick your device so that one is out of the question, unless you somehow ported it to work on your tablet chroot is the only way.

Comment: where on my hard drive does the nexus 7 installer download the install files not the installer program file but the "boot.img etc." files as i want to see what the files are that are used to boot ubuntu as i will try to make some sort of port.